# Posting attached file to a web service via httpwebrequest

Tags: c#, web-services, post, httpwebrequest

I am currently trying to post an xml file to a web service.

This is my current code

```
 var tempFileLocation = @"c:\Temp\";             

            XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
            xdoc.LoadXml(item);
            xdoc.Save(tempFileLocation + "\\pcf.xml");

            var url = "https://Siteaddress/xml.aspx";

            UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
            byte[] byte1 = encoding.GetBytes(xdoc.InnerXml);
            HttpWebRequest submissionRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            submissionRequest.KeepAlive = true;
            submissionRequest.Method = "POST";
            submissionRequest.ContentType = "multipart/form-data";
            submissionRequest.ContentLength = byte1.Length;
            submissionRequest.Timeout = 10000;
            submissionRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate"); 

            Stream requestStream = submissionRequest.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(byte1, 0, byte1.Length);
            requestStream.Close();

            XmlDocument responseXMLDocument = new XmlDocument();

            HttpWebResponse submissionAcknowledgement = (HttpWebResponse)submissionRequest.GetResponse();

            if (submissionAcknowledgement.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                responseXMLDocument.Load(submissionAcknowledgement.GetResponseStream());

            }
```

I then receive the following message.

bad Request.Form[pcfxml] - this should have been attached as POST

How should I post the xml file as an attachment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I found a solution I needed to pass a NameValueCollection through a WebClient

```
var url = string.Format("https://Site-Address/xml.aspx");

        NameValueCollection nvc = new NameValueCollection();
        nvc.Add("pcfxml", productSerialized);

        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        var response = wc.UploadValues(url, nvc);
```

Thanks Aundy for your response I had played around with boundary.

Answer (score 0):

Seems boundary is missing.  Need to set the boundary for all multipart upload...

```
boundary = GetBoundary();

request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
```

and boundary should be like below.  Please note whenever you write a byte into the request stream, please make sure you have mentioned the boundary.

```
private static string GetBoundary()
{
    return "--------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");
}
```